# VSccode can't recognize html5lib (I installed it)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, html5lib

##### Visual Studio Code not reading html5lib

I am using `bs4` in VS Code, along with `html5lib`, but VS Code is indicating that it does not exist (I installed it using the command prompt).

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = " "
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To assist you better, could you please provide the exact error message that you're encountering? This will help us understand the issue and provide a more precise solution. Thank you!

Comment: show exactly how you installed it

Answer (score 0):

Usually, **ModuleNotFound** error was caused by incorrect python interpreter if you have installed the package.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and search for "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you install your python package in.